# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'embeddingstore'

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to run code that contains parts that need to import the module "**embeddingstore**":

```
 from embeddingstore.core.contracts import (
    EmbeddingModelType,
    StorageType,
    StoreCoreConfig,)
    
 from embeddingstore.core.embeddingstore_core import EmbeddingStoreCore
```

But I keep getting the error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'embeddingstore'**

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'embeddingstore'
  File "D:\Users\username\gitApps\filefolder\app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from embeddingstore.core.contracts import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'embeddingstore'
```

Tried a couple things but still no work:

1. In the original environment, run `pip install embedding`  , run 'python main.py'

[image]

Result: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'embeddingstore'

Check module installation with `pip list` and it shows **embeddingstore** is indeed installed

[image]

2. Uninstall the module, install again => same result
3. Create a venv, and install the module, but still get the same issue

[image]

Run `pip list` and it has been successfully installed

[image]

I can't figure out why the issue persist, appreciate if anyone could help!

Comment: Can you show your full stack trace?

Comment: Just in case. You do not have an embeddingstore.py file next to main.py, do you?

Comment: Hi @journypy  I have added the full stack trace, is there anything I could provide?

Comment: Hi  @Guillaume, no I don't have that, it's my first time trying to run this, I don't know if it's necessary or not to add embeddingstore.py file next to main.py

Comment: I'm assuming you `pip install embeddingstore` in your active venv

Comment: Hi @journypy 
Yes I have installed on both active environment and venv, but both showed the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link on [azureml-examples](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/generative-ai/promptflow/create_faiss_index.ipynb)

Maybe you could try using:

```
from promptflow_vectordb.core.contracts import (
    EmbeddingModelType,
    StorageType,
    StoreCoreConfig,
)
```

It worked on my environment.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the right module that I should've imported.